# Number of solutions for $x^3+ax^2+b$

Tags: roots, cubics, stationary-point

Sketch the curve 
$\mathrm{f}(x)=x^{3}+Ax^{2}+B$
first in the case $A>0$ and $B>0$, and then in the case $A<0$ and $B>0.$

Show that the equation 
$x^{3}+ax^{2}+b=0$,
where $a$ and $b$ are real, will have three distinct real roots
if 
$27b^{2}+3a^{3}b<0,$
but will have fewer than three if 
$27b^{2}+4a^{3}b<0.$

I worked through this question. I give a sketch:
$f'(x) = 3x^2 + 2Ax$
so the turning points are at 0 and $-\frac{2A}{3}$.

$f(-2A/3) = \frac{4A^3}{27} + B$

If $A>0$, $B\geq 0$, the both stationary points of the cub are non-negative. - 1 solution or 2

If $A<0$, $B\geq 0$, then we need $f(-2A/3)<0$ for 3 solutions, else there is only 1 or 2.

Similar argument can be made when $B<0$.

The condition I arrived was: depending on whether $27b^2+4a^3b<0$, we have 3 or less solutions. This is different to the result in the question. Why is that?

This is STEP Question 93-S1-Q7 found here:

http://stepdatabase.maths.org/database/index.html#

Comment: Please, revise the sense of the inequalities in your text. I think you mispelled something due to the copy-paste.

Comment: Which one do you think I mispelt?

Comment: Second paragraph, two "$<0$" cases. In paragraphs 5 and 6 you consider both $A>0$ and $A<0$, but then you explicitly add $A<0$ again in paragraph 7. I think you already have the main steps of the proof; you just need to make yourself clear.

Comment: I didn't mispelt the question. I think the question is wrong. Notice it says 3 rather than 4 in one of the questions and they both <0 statements. In fact that cannot possible hold because one one of these statements implies the other.

Comment: You are right. The question is wrong. The second case (the one for less than 3 solutions) should be "$>0$"

Comment: and it should be 4 in both inequalities.

Comment: Yes. It's $27b^2+4a^3b$ in both